# How to separate routes out from a single main method, so that I can handle requests in diff classes like servlet

Tags: java, backend, spark-java

I'm using [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) framework to power my back-end Restful API.

From all the examples that I have read, all requests are handled in the `main` method. Are there ways that I can separate different requests handlers into different classes, just like the way how **Servlet** does it, so that the code structure may looks nicer.

Answer (score 3):

First, as @gurpreet wrote, you can create a server object and thus transfer the routing from the main routine into a method of the server class. This gives you a first step to cleaner code.

But I suppose you want to extract the logic that is done in the route handler into a different object. For this you could define a class which I here just name SampleResource that has two methods:

```
public class SampleResource {
  public Object methodOne(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
    // do something useful to create you result object
    return result;
  }

  public Object methodTwo(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
    // do something useful to create you result object
    return result;
  }
}
```

In your main Server class you can instantiate and use the SampleResource by using method references:

```
res = new SampleResource();
get("/one", res::methodOne);
get("/two", res::methodTwo);
```

So you can group the logic of your application into Resource classes, this is an approach that is more similar to the classic JAX-RS annotated resource classes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes definitely, you can go completely Object-Oriented if you wish. Here's an example class for you to build on.

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

/**
* Defines a "server" which is a wrapper for
* the client to easily communicate with.
*/
public class Server {

    // Main entry point
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Let's go object oriented.
        new Server();
    }

     /**
     * Loads necessary server .
     */
     Server() {
        // This equals "resources/public"
        // using maven
        staticFileLocation("/public");

        // Setup routes
        defineRoutes();

     }

     /**
     * Define your routes in here
     */
     private void defineRoutes() {

        // Lands on homepage
        get("/", (request, response) -> {
            // ...
        }
        post("/foo", (request, response) -> {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```